# Where are the missing speeds in my KitchenAid mixer

Tags: equipment, stand-mixer

I have an artisan KitchenAid mixer, model KSM150, everywhere on the internet, including in the [KitchenAid site](https://www.kitchenaid.com.au/products/ksm150-artisan-stand-mixers-0) it says that there are 10 working speeds, but the speed selector on my mixer has only 6 working position (and another one for off), there are also corresponding markings on the mixer which are fitting the same number: 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.
See in this picture from the internet:

[image]

Where are the 3, 5, 7 and 9 speeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned in the user manual for your stand mixer (the larger more detailed booklet, not the quick start pamphlet).

Those speeds exist on your machine, they just aren't labeled. The odd speeds aren't commonly used, so by design the lever is predisposed to "notch" at the evens, and the lever naturally wants to find a place there. However if you need more granular control of your machine, you can adjust the lever to stop in between speeds.  For instance, if you want to set to speed five you would adjust the lever to speed four, and then carefully move the lever forward until it sits between four and six-- that is speed five, and the lever will stay without snapping either forward to speed six or backward to speed four.

Comment: I don't own a Kitchen Aid, but  Kenwood, so this is really 'idle curiosity'... Is it just a variable potentiometer rather than specific speeds, but just has physical sprung/indented 'notches' it prefers to stop at? My Kenwood has no notches at all, it's just a simple vari-pot with gradually increasing speed, more like the volume knob on a hifi.

Comment: @Tetsujin I believe that's the case, but tbh I'm not mechanically inclined enough to know for sure (and I'm not home to check the book and see if it says).

Comment: Good answer, it works exactly like that. The in-between speeds really aren't hard to set, in practice I rarely use them.